# How to extract date and time from a video

Tags: c#

[image]I have a video and some important sensor data which is stored in the database. The sensor data has time stamp. Is it possible for me to pull the date time of the video from the video file so that at any given time i can play the video and show the sensor data side by side. How is this done in C#. File creation date and modified date are completely different. Video date time you find printed on the video when you play

Comment: File creation date and modified date are completely different. Video date time you find printed on the video when you play

Comment: Also, timestamp from sensor can have difference from date of video file, because of region and time synchronization.

Comment: That is taken care of. We have sensor and video date time the same

Comment: It looks like the name of the mp4 file contains the correct start DateTime.  Could you combine that start time with how long the video has been playing for?

Comment: The time displayed there is different for different frames and is changing correctly. So what I am looking for a method to extract this test.https://vimeo.com/173064474

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, your video stream is saved into file chunks, so you basically don't need to look at video - you have **file creation** time and **duration**, with some adjustments (calculating how long it takes for camera to save file, or parsing this name which, will probably be your correct time) you can calculate file, and video position in it. 
This is easy and good way of doing things if you don't care much about milliseconds.

If by luck your video camera stores time in subtitles, then you can use this command to extract it:

> ffmpeg -i myHomeVideo.mp4

Hardest way would be to use machine learning for this, but I think this is overpower for this task and provide more errors. For example, if by chance camera drivers will change and position of time text in it too - you have a problem.

Comment: How machine learning, could you please explain a bit more. I am wondering if this is saved as a text in video, then it should be extractable using some tool.

Comment: Used EMGUCV for getting time. CapProp.PosMsec